# Static code analysis for groovy with eclipse

Tags: groovy, sonarlint-eclipse, codenarc

I want to add static code analysis plugin to eclipse (Eclipse Mars 4.6). For that I added sonarlint plugin which contains rules for groovy project as well. But it could not analyse groovy files or can give any suggestions for the same.

I searched over net and found codenarc can be used for the same and sonarlint is also using reports by codenarc but codenarc plugin for eclipse is available till eclipse 4.1 only, not supported for the versions higher than that.

Has anybody tried anything to do static code analysis with groovy.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you are correct. The eclipse plugin has not been updated in a while.  If you are interested in taking that over, it would be much appreciated.  As an alternate solution, you can use codenarc at the build tool level. Depending on your system, there should be a plugin for you: http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-other-tools-frameworks.html